# how I can put background gif/video in the view?

Tags: swift, webview, view, background, gif

I want to put a gif as a background, I get it but the background takes time to appear. this is my code

in viewdidload I have this

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "4", ofType: "gif")
        let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

        let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webViewBG.load(gif! as Data, mimeType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
        webViewBG.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.view.insertSubview(webViewBG, at: 0)
     }
}
```

I also had the idea of putting the code in viewwillappear but the background is slow to appear.

how i can fix it? any suggestions?

Comment: Web views are expected to take some time to load, since they need a whole infrastructure behind.

Comment: I know. this is the way I put a gif, if I put an image view doesn't load the gif.:( Is there another way to put a gif?

Comment: Check this question, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45745432/1974224